# Checking if a file exists, and if not display a message on screen until it does exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a website where a user can press a button and create a dynamic report. The report is creating successfully, but can take some time (written in ASP.NET). (Sidenote: the report is created by an external VB program - this is all working fine!!)

If the file doesn't yet exist, I want to display a message on screen with 'Please wait whilst your file is created', but at the moment, no message is appearing but as soon as the file exists in the folder, it downloads as expected.

How can I get the message to display whilst the report is being generated?

My code is as follows:

```
while (true)
    try
    {
        string exportDateFileName = exportRequest.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss");
        Response.ContentType = "APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM";
        String Header = "Attachment; Filename=PartPrediction" + ddl_country.SelectedItem.Text + ".xlsx";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", Header);
        // System.IO.FileInfo Dfile = new System.IO.FileInfo("~/Transfer/Exports/"+ exportDateFileName+".xlsx");
        System.IO.FileInfo Dfile = new System.IO.FileInfo("~/Transfer/Exports/Book1.xlsx");

        Response.WriteFile(Dfile.FullName);
        Response.End();
    }
    //wait for the file to be created 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        if(!File.Exists("~/Transfer/_Exports/Book1.xlsx"))
        {

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
       downloadingMessage.Visible=true;
    }
```

Any advice will be much appreciated!

Comment: use while(!File.Exists("~/Transfer/_Exports/Book1.xlsx")){//Do Nothing} where you want to wait for file to be created.

Comment: @MuhammadRamzan thanks, but i want a message to appear on screen saying to wait whilst the file is created

Comment: One word of advice: just because a file exists does not automatically mean that it has completed writing to disk. There is a difference between when the file started existing, and when the (other application) has finished writing to the file.

Comment: simple show a non blocking UI before waiting while loop and after while loop hide that.

Comment: thanks @Flater. I take it there's no real way of knowing that the file has completely been created?

Comment: @MuhammadRamzan thanks, do you have an example i could use?

Comment: @akb29: Not unless the program that writes the file makes it intentionally obvious. E.g. while writing, it writes the data to `myfile.temp.txt` and when done, it renames the file to `myfile.txt`. Just a random example. But you cannot know that the previous application is done with its work unless the previous application lets you know (in any way) that the work is done.

Answer (score 0):

implement a push mechanism and check if whether file exists or not

```
if(!File.Exists("~/Transfer/_Exports/Book1.xlsx"))
{
  PushSomeMessage("file is not ready yet, please wait");
}
```

Comment: thanks, but i get the error "The name 'PushSomeMessage' does not exist in the current context". Am I missing an assembly reference?

Comment: as I said before you should add pushing library for example SignalR so you can implement PushSomeMessage in your codes